# Vue ChartKick - different colours for bar chart

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, chartkick

I use a vertical bar chart and I want to specify different colors for each bar:

main.js

```
import Chartkick from 'vue-chartkick';
import Chart from 'chart.js';
Vue.use(Chartkick.use(Chart));
```

File.vue

```
<column-chart :data="chartData" width="800px" :colors="['#0b6e00', '#006ca2', '#ff3333', '#d60001']"></column-chart>
```

But only the first color is used and all bars have the same colour.

[image]

I tried to pass a `:library` attribute with backGround colour parameter as well without luck. Line chart accepts different colours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work if you define `:colors` as a nested array as follows:

```
<column-chart 
  :data="chartData" 
  width="800px" 
  :colors="[['#0b6e00', '#006ca2', '#ff3333', '#d60001']]">
</column-chart>
```

[image]

Please have a look at the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-chartkick-chartjs-column-chart)

Comment: Thank you. I was about to switch the library. What is the reason for having two arrays?

Comment: @Leos Literak: Unfortunately I don't know about the reason and I never heard about `vue-chartkick` before. I was making different attempts and suddenly it worked.

Comment: Very weird :) + Zero docs. Nice solution :) In my opinion, it's better to use the core chart.js library (For simple color setting you need to open StackOverflow Q).

Comment: @LeosLiterak By having an array inside the array, you define the colors one by one. But if you want all the columns to have to same color, you can just do `:colors="['color']"`

Comment: Thank you for an explanation

Comment: Excellent Thanks! Makes my day :)